# Does onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() calls each time on configuration change?

Tags: android

Does [onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29) calls each time on configuration change, i.e. when I change orientation of my device? I override it and checked it does, but what confuses me is that this note in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29).

> This function is called purely as an
>   optimization, and you **must not rely on
>   it being called**.

Does it guaranteed this method is called on orientation change?

Comment: Similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720927/should-i-implement-onretainnonconfigurationinstance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This note means that your app's functionality should not *depend* on `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` being called for proper function. That is, your program should not crash or behave erratically if a device is rotated, but `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` is *not* called.

If it *does* get called, then you can use it to speed up the re-creation of your Activity.

Comment: So what are the circumstances it would not be called then?

Comment: It is implementation specific. The documentation is basically giving Android distribution implementors the freedom to handle this how they want, and warning app developers that you can't count on it.

Comment: @AndroidNoob: To expand slightly, it means you should ALWAYS check that getLastNonConfigurationInstance() hasn't returned 'null'. If it does return null then your code needs to adapt accordingly.