# Softkeyboard, Edit text and the Orientation change

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, orientation-changes

First of all I'm handling the orientation changes from code, I need that app will go through `onCreate()` only once and therefore in `onConfigurationChanged` I manually perform initialization when necessary.

**About the problem:**

When I hit the EditText activate the SoftKeyboard, and change the orientation after what I write something in new orientation and submit that (ok or just back button) the text wouldn't appear in the EditText, the text that was written **after** orientation change!

I can save the text from `EditText` before configchange and then resume it, but if I continue typing in the same softkeyboard after changing the orientation, symbols won't show up, I can type but there's nothing appearing on the screen i.e in the `EditText`.

I think it's because the SoftKeyboard loosing the link between itself and the original EditText when changing the orientation, because I reinitialize the layout and EditText after configchange but do nothing to say about it to SoftKeyboard, in fact, I even don't know if this is possible. I don't know how to make it work, maybe someone had such an issue.

P.S. Please don't ask me to use TextWatchers - they're not an option.

**UPD**

I've uploaded the video that shows the problem in act.
https://youtu.be/eoEBjooYNAU

Here's the code of that app:

*Manifest*

```
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

*MainActivity*:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText txtMain;
private void Init() {
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
txtMain = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMain);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Init();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
String txtMainText = txtMain.getText().toString(); //SAVING THE STATE
Init(); //RELOADING RESOURCES AND VARS REFRESHING ACCORDING TO THE NEW LAYOUT
txtMain.setText(txtMainText); //RESTORING THE STATE
}
}
```

*EditText*:

```
<EditText
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:id="@+id/txtMain"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

**I really need to solve the problem, maybe I've done something stupid or it's some wide-known bug, anyway, I need your help!**

UPD
Is there really no one to help me?(

Comment: It's problem. You can't use onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState(). You can't recreate Activity ?

Comment: That's right, I can't recreate Activity on every configchange it would be too slow to have it that way, because in this activity (in my original activity) there are many data that loads to spinners and objects.

Comment: Maybe help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285877/which-one-to-use-onsaveinstancestate-vs-onretainnonconfigurationinstance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have solved the issue by using the `Fragment` class, as it was described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).